# How to test attr_accessible fields in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

So we have been setting up `attr_accessible` and `attr_protected` on many fields through out our Rails 3.2 app. For now we really don't test to ensure that these fields are protected.

So I decided to google some answers and stumbled upon this solution:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_accessible do |attribute|
  match do |response|
    response.send("#{attribute}=", :foo)
    response.send("#{attribute}").eql? :foo
  end
  description { "be accessible :#{attribute}" }
  failure_message_for_should { ":#{attribute} should be accessible" }
  failure_message_for_should_not { ":#{attribute} should not be accessible" }
end
```

But this solution only test's to see if the method is responding. What I need is a way for me to test that attributes can and can't be mass assigned. I honestly love the syntax

```
it { should_not be_accessible :field_name }
it { should be_accessible :some_field }
```

Does anyone have a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Consider using [Permitters](https://github.com/permitters/permitters) or [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) instead of mass assignment security (attr_accessible + attr_protected), which is going away in Rails 4.

Comment: Already use it in production. This was something from when ForbiddenAttributes wasn't mainstream.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can check if the attribute is on `#accessible_attributes` list

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_accessible do |attribute|
  match do |response|
    response.class.accessible_attributes.include?(attribute)
  end
  description { "be accessible :#{attribute}" }
  failure_message_for_should { ":#{attribute} should be accessible" }
  failure_message_for_should_not { ":#{attribute} should not be accessible" }
end
```

Comment: You can put this code in a `spec/support/be_accessible_matcher.rb` by example

Comment: Now why didn't I think to check that array

Comment: shingara, how to execute the code in be_accessible_matcher.rb under support? rspec spec/support does not execute anything. thanks.

Comment: code is not execute ask a real SO question if you want answer

Answer (score 29):

I was looking for something similar and then I was told about the shoulda-matcher allow_mass_assigment_of.  That ended up working for me without creating a custom matcher.

```
it { should allow_mass_assignment_of :some_field }
it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of :field_name }
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This is more or less how it is implemented above I would suppose. However, I did not know this existed. Up vote for you

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason RSpec is tripping up on juicedM3's answer above like mine was you can do something like this:

```
specify { expect { Model.new(unaccessible_attr: value) }.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error) }
```

Comment: This is the way to go with the new expectation style.