# Error on 10.1.3 "User/Micropost associations"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails and making my way through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial. I've hit a bug I can't seem to fix on Chapter 10 (specifically, 10.1.3 "User/Micropost associations"). The error I run into is when I execute the following rspec command:

$ bundle exec rspec spec/models

It raises the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) Micropost accessible attributes should not allow access to user_id
     ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mexpect do←[0m
       ←[31mexpected ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error but nothing was
raised←[0m
←[36m     # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (req
uired)>'←[0m

Finished in 5.79 seconds
←[31m27 examples, 1 failure←[0m

Failed examples:

←[31mrspec ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:27←[0m ←[36m# Micropost accessible at
tributes should not allow access to user_id←[0m
```

This is the code for micropost_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Micropost do

let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before { @micropost = user.microposts.build(content: "Lorem ipsum") }

subject { @micropost }

  it { should respond_to(:content) }
  it { should respond_to(:user_id) }
  it { should respond_to(:user) }
  its(:user) { should == user }

  it { should be_valid }




  describe "when user_id is not present" do
    before { @micropost.user_id = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end


  describe "accessible attributes" do
    it "should not allow access to user_id" do
      expect do
       Micropost.new(user_id: user.id)
      end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end
  end
end
```

application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

  if defined?(Bundler)
 # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
 Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
 # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
 # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
   # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
   # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
   # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
   # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
   # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
# :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
# config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

# Activate observers that should always be running.
# config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

# Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
# Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
# config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

# The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
# config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
# config.i18n.default_locale = :de
# Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
config.encoding = "utf-8"

# Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
config.filter_parameters += [:password]

# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
 end
 end
```

micropost.rb...

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Thai

Comment: What about the model it's complaining about? Also, what Rails version are you using?

Comment: Hi @Dave, to your question, I'm running Rails 3.2.9.

Answer (score 0):

So `expected ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error but nothing was
raised` when `Micropost.new(user_id: user.id)` is called.

For it to work correctly:

1. The Rails application should be configured to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible parameters; in rails versions before `3.2.3` this was on by default; in previous versions, it has to be done by the following line in `config/application.rb` as detailed in [Listing 10.6 of RailsTutorial book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#code-application_whitelist):

   `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true`
2. There shouldn't be a `attr_accessible :user_id` in the `micropost.rb` model file.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I had made those updates; however, the same error persists. I've updated my initial question to include the code you referred to.

Comment: Might seem obvious, but if you made changes to **application.rb**, did you make sure to stop and re-start your rails server?

Comment: @Paul, I did what you said (rails s and then rails c); unfortunately, the error still persists :-(.

Comment: If you're using spork, then remember to restart that as well otherwise your tests will still be running under the pre-edited environment.

Comment: @Paul, is there an easy way (specifically a command) to restart spork? I haven't had much luck with the spork-guard gem. Thanks!

Comment: Not that I use or know of.  I just use Ctrl-C to stop spork and then `$ spork` to restart if ever I change any config files that aren't in the `app` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
```

To your application.rb file, what I found out is that if not strict, it would just throw a Warning but not an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I tried all of the solutions above with no luck. I also notice that Hartl's more recent editions of the book for Rails 4 do not contain those tests, so I suspect this approach to testing accessibility does not work in later versions. Perhaps an expert (someone who isn't running through the Rails Tutorial) can chime in.

But.... I noticed this response in another StackOverflow thread recommending the "shoulda-matchers" Gem to test it, and that solved the problem for me (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11876425/3899955). In investigating that Gem, I find it is a nice way to produce readable tests for a number of common ActiveModel, ActiveRecord, and ActionController tests. I am happy to be adding that to my quiver, perhaps you will be too.

I don't take credit for that answer, just wanted to post this so if anyone else is running in to this frustration doing Chapter 10.5, or completing exercise 6 in Chapter 9.